# Is it possible to add the latest version of a dependency to pubspec.yaml without finding it myself?

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-pub

Lets say I am starting a new dart project. I have a few packages on [pub.dev](https://pub.dev) I know that I want to use, and I want to use the most recent version of these packages.

Right now, I open my browser and go to [pub.dev](https://pub.dev) and find *each* package, then check the **Versions** or **Installing** tab to find out what the latest version is so I can put that in my `pubspec.yaml`. Then I can run `pub get`

Using npm, you can run `npm install <package>` and npm will automatically fetch the latest version of the package and add it to `package.json`

Is there a pub command, syntax for pubspec.yaml, or something else that will make pub resolve the latest version of a package and use it in my project, without having to manually look up the latest version?

Comment: If you *always* want to use whatever the latest version is, you can just leave the version field blank in the `pubspec.yaml` file.

Answer (score 1):

Normally in Flutter, the packages which you want to use need to be added to pubspec.yaml and run pub get. But there are also some IDE plugins like npm.

For example, Pubspec Assist is using on Visual Studio, you can add or update your dependencies without going pub.dev. But you have to know which packages do you want to use at least for a time.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=jeroen-meijer.pubspec-assist

Answer (score 0):

Simply enter the following command in the terminal

```
flutter pub add provider
```

Of course, where it says provider, put the package you want to install.

The package with the latest version is automatically added to your pubspec.yaml.

Otherwise you can always do what @jamesdlin said and leave the version field empty.